How to use okhttp-coroutines module from okhttp3?
There is a Gradle module called okhttp-coroutines in OkHttp repository but I'm not sure if it's published to maven because I tried using it and I didn't get any error but also the import okhttp3.coroutines is invalid as the coroutines doesn't exist

implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-coroutines:4.12.0")



I don't see any 4.12.0 version of that library having been released, only 5.0.0 (alpha): https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp-coroutines

I though it's the same version as OkHttp like Kotlin, thank you for the reply

It's looks like there is a different version for okhttp-coroutines (not the same as okhttp) which can be found in maven repository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp-coroutines
so this works:

implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-coroutines:5.0.0-alpha.14")


I know this thanks to Micheal
I should have done more search before posting a question.
